# How to change total value for progress bar in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am using primeng progress bar

I want to change the total value from which p-progress bar calculates its %. By default 100 is there, I want to change it to 200.
Sample code is given here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-progressbar-demo-3bui5q?file=src/app/app.component.ts

In html file:

```
<h5>Dynamic</h5>
<p-progressBar [value]="value"></p-progressBar>
</div>
```

In ts file:

```
value: number = 0;

ngOnInit() {
this.value = 90;
//What is my total is 200 and out of that I want to show 90, so progress bar % should reduce,
//Want to change the total 100 to 200.
}
```

Comment: It’s a percentage so if your max is 200, you’ll have to divide every value by 2..?

Comment: max: number = 200 and then in your init do this.value = (90 / this.max) * 100;

Comment: there is no inbuilt property by which we can increase the max value or set the property like we are setting for value?

Comment: For p-progressBar? I don’t think so?

Comment: okay. This worked for now this.value = (90 / this.max) * 100.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this today. I don't think this is very possible, but I found a solution.

.html file

```
<div class="progress-container">
    <span>{{progressString}}</span>
    <p-progressBar [value]="progress" [showValue]="false">
    </p-progressBar>
</div>
```

.css file

```
.progress-container{
    position: relative;
}
.progress-container span{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
    z-index: 99;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

**and most importantly in the .ts file for example my value was 1/4. We need to convert this value to a percentage and send it to value. I'm writing this as static, but you can change these values.**

.ts file

```
setProgress() {
        let a = 1;
        let b = 4;
        this.progress = (a/b)*100;
        this.progressString = `${a}/${b} Question`;
    }
```